# how to save file in another machine in the same network in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation, remote-desktop

I have to save the uploaded document into another local machine. But I was not clear how to use impersonation in my code.

I have used the following code.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int result = 0,result1=0;
        string attachmentpath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\pr84528\\My Documents\\PRABU\\Tech\\Dot Net\\DocumentManager\\Attachments\\";
....................................................................................
....................................................................................
if(fuDocument.HasFile)
    fuDocument.SaveAs(attachmentpath + fuDocument.FileName);
....................................................................................
....................................................................................
}
```

Comment: Save to `\\computername\c$\sharedfolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is your solution.
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/853352-create-text-file-network-path-using-c

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNC path to a public share where you have write rights.

(ex. \\computerName\PublicShareFolder)

You can check if you have rights via ACL (create a DirectoryInfo object for that path and get ACL for it to check if you have write rights) and then you can write to that path.